# Winsocket threadding for Client organisation crashes.

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock

Main idea is:

First thread just wait for connection of a client. So this thread is a manager (communicationthread).
As soon as accept == true, this thread creates another thread ( vector of threads) where the **recv** and **send** take place.
This ist the Implementation:

```
bool CServerClientCommunication::OpenConnectionForClient(int Port)
            {
            long rc;
            SOCKADDR_IN addr;

                rc=StartWinsock();
                if(rc!=0)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                server=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
                if(server==INVALID_SOCKET)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                memset(&addr,0,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
                addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
                addr.sin_port=htons(Port);
                addr.sin_addr.s_addr=ADDR_ANY;

                rc=bind(server,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
                if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                long rc2=listen(server,10);
                if(rc2==SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    return false;
                }

            WAIT_FOR_CLIENT:
            if(Terminated)
            {
                return false;
            }
                // Accept Client to Serversocket
                client=accept(server,NULL,NULL);
                // Check if Accept failed
                if(client==INVALID_SOCKET)
                {
                    if( Clients.size()>0)
                       {
                           for (int i = 0; i < Clients.size(); i++)
                           {
                                if(Clients[i]->isKilled == true)
                                {
                                    Clients[i]->Terminate();
                                    Clients[i]->WaitFor();
                                    delete Clients[i];
                                    Clients[i] = NULL;
                                }
                           }
                       }
                    goto WAIT_FOR_CLIENT;
                }
                       CServerClientProcessing * ServerClientProcessing = new CServerClientProcessing(true);
                       ServerClientProcessing->FreeOnTerminate = false;
                       Clients.push_back(ServerClientProcessing);
                       ServerClientProcessing->client = client;
                       Sleep(100);
                       if( Clients.size()>0)
                       {
                           for (int i = 0; i < Clients.size(); i++)
                           {
                                if(Clients[i]->isKilled == true)
                                {
                                    Clients[i]->Terminate();
                                    Clients[i]->WaitFor();
                                    delete Clients[i];
                                    Clients[i] = NULL;
                                }
                           }
                       }
                       ServerClientProcessing->Resume();
                       goto WAIT_FOR_CLIENT;
            }

            int CServerClientCommunication::StartWinsock()
            {
                WSADATA wsa;
                return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&wsa);
            }

            bool CServerClientCommunication::GetConnectionStatus()
            {
                return server != -1;
            }

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            void __fastcall CServerClientCommunication::Execute()
            {
                int Port = PortProperties->ClientPort;
                bool check=OpenConnectionForClient(Port);
            }
```

We got here a vector of threads wich do recv and send (processing threads). If we loose the communication with client, we set the bool isKilled on true, so the communicationthread can terminate this thread in vector.
This is the implementation for processingthread:

```
        void __fastcall CServerClientProcessing::Execute()
        {
        AnsiString Answer = "";
        AnsiString CheckCase = "GetTemperature";
        AnsiString CheckCase2 = "GetSetTemperature";
        AnsiString ToSend = "";
        AnsiString Error = "WRONG_ORDER";
        AnsiString AllUp;
        int ByteOffset = 0;
        int Receive = 0;
        int Send = 0;
        char recvbuf[255];

            while(!Terminated)
            {
                memset(recvbuf, 0x00, sizeof(recvbuf));
                int StartTime = GetTickCount(); //100
                ByteOffset = 0;
                while(GetTickCount()-StartTime<1000 && !Terminated && isKilled == false)
                {
                    // recv function to recieve information from server
                    // bitwise recieve information from client
                    Receive = recv(client,&recvbuf[ByteOffset],1,0);
                    // Receive > 0 true.
                    if (Receive > 0 )
                    {
                        // find last char \r and delete it
                        if(recvbuf[ByteOffset] == '\r')
                        {
                            recvbuf[ByteOffset] = '\0' ;
                            AnsiString temp =  recvbuf;
                            AllUp = recvbuf;
                            AllUp=AllUp.UpperCase();
                            break;
                        }
                        ByteOffset++;
                    }
                    if (Receive < 0)
                    {
                       int value = WSAGetLastError();
                       if (value == 10054 || value == 10093)
                       {
                            isKilled = true;
                            closesocket(client);
                            break;
                       }
                       else
                            continue;
                    }
                    if (Receive = 0)
                    {
                        isKilled = true;
                        closesocket(client);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // check content of receive
                if(AllUp.Length()!= NULL)
                {
                    CheckCase = CheckCase.UpperCase();
                    if(AllUp == CheckCase)
                    {
                        ToSend = FloatToStr(ConnectionThread->CurrentTemperature/10.0);
                        Answer = ToSend + "\r";
                        // copy information into buffer to send the answer client
                        memcpy(recvbuf,Answer.c_str(), Answer.Length());
                    }
                    CheckCase2 = CheckCase2.UpperCase();
                    if( AllUp == CheckCase2)
                    {
                        ToSend = FloatToStr(ConnectionThread->TemperatureLimit1/10.0);
                        Answer = ToSend + "\r";
                        // copy information into buffer to send the answer client
                        memcpy(recvbuf,Answer.c_str(), Answer.Length());
                    }
                    if( AllUp == CheckCase && AllUp == CheckCase2 )
                    {
                        Error =  Error + "\r";
                        memcpy(recvbuf,Error.c_str(), Error.Length());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Error = Error + "\r";
                    memcpy(recvbuf,Error.c_str(), Error.Length());
                }
                // send answer(buffer) to client
                    Send = send( client, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0 );
                    Sleep(1000);
                    // check if failed sending
                    if (Send == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        closesocket(client);
                        isKilled = true;
                        WSACleanup();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

As soon as i open a client everything works fine. But as I close the client the unwanted things happen: I can´t connect another client and the new client dies. Also two clients at the same time isn´t possible.

Is there a need of Critical section, or is it a logical problem of the structure? I also get a access violation because of deleted vector, even i check if it is not empty.

Comment: One thing, you call `WSAStartup` once, but you call `WSACleanup` for every client. There are probably other problems, and probably also in the code not posted. You should post this on codereview in addition to this question, because there are tons of things that aren't right, but it's not appropriate for SO.

Comment: @ElderBug Please read our [on-topic help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Working code has been a prerequisite for as long as I can remember.

Comment: actually this is the whole code. the rest is irrelevant. communicationthread is executed and as client is connected communicationthread creates this vector with processing threads

Comment: Lama, @ElderBug inapproriately suggested you migrate your question to CodeReview instead of keep it here. We're just pointing out that the question, if migrated in its current state, would be closed on CR. There's no issue with your question, just the migration suggestion. :-) Because your code has known bugs (you acknowledge a known problem), we can't review on CodeReview until its resolved. This question should stay here until those problems are fixed.

Comment: Are you trying to connect using the same port? If so, that causes this kind of problems. And probably you aren't properly closing the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

It was bad thinking, because i was using TCP_Socket and this enable secure information transport. So I have to read the information.

Instead of it, I broke up after finding \r. The rest of the message, about 230 signs were still in traffic.

Thats the reason why it broke up the connection. I had to send the length of th message not of the buffer.